# How can i get a value from a select box and use it to get a response from an API?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to make a random number facts app and that is triggered by the input of a number. The app works fine but I want to be able to also select a year fact or a math fact but it shows me just number facts even though I select year/math. The API I use allows me to use that format (e.g. http://numbersapi.com/2001/year). Also, I don't have errors in JSlint.

```
let fact = document.querySelector("#fact");
let factText = document.querySelector("#factText");
let numberInput = document.querySelector("#numberInput");
let selecter = document.querySelector("#numberSelect");

numberInput.addEventListener("input", getFactAjax);

function getFactAjax() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let number = numberInput.value;
  let numberType = "";
    switch(selecter.value){
      case 1:
        numberType = "";
        break;
      case 2:
        numberType = "/year";
        break;
      case 3:
        numberType = "/math";
    }
    xhr.open("GET", "http://numbersapi.com/"+ number + numberType);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status == 200 && number != ""){
           fact.style.display = "block";
           factText.innerHTML = this.responseText;
           }
    };
    xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: Post up your html also.

Comment: I'm guessing selecter.value is string and not integer. Try with "case '1': ..." etc

Comment: consider using `onerror` as well since you use `onload` and not `onreadystatechange`.  Values of select elements are string, use a string in your case statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input.value` returns a string. A comparison done with the strict equality operator `===` returns `false` for string/int comparisons. The switch statement uses strict equality. Thus, when you directly give the switch statement the string returned from `input.value` while using numbers in the cases, none of the cases will match the string given, and the whole thing basically does nothing. The easy solution is to use strings in the cases, e.g. `case "1":` instead of `case 1:`. The "proper" solution is to convert the string to a number first, e.g. by using `parseInt`.

[Input reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

[Equality reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)